# Oracle Custom type parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, odac

i am new to oracle .I have procedure which has a param like this

```
@param1 title_type.title_type_code%type
```

title_type is custom type
ok.. now
**How do I pass the parameter from c# using ODAC( OracleParameter object)
%type is confusing do you need to pass as object or  pass as string
    Anyone know please help??**

Answer (score 0):

This is just a reference to the type that `title_type.title_type_code` is using, as an alternative to hardcoding the type in two places.

You need to look up the definition of that table, and pass the parameter as whatever that is (could be VARCHAR, could be NUMBER, I doubt that it is an object).